# My robot framework jar file with dependencies after maven install command is shown as corrupt file, Kindly assist

Tags: robotframework

A snapshot.jar file of robot framework and its dependencies was created in eclipse after running maven install command. But the jar file is not able to execute my robot test cases as an error throws up: corrupt jar file.

I have searched about configuring pom.xml for robot framework as suggested in [How to run test cases using robot framework jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28041594/how-to-run-test-cases-using-robot-framework-jar-file),  but could not build a proper jar file.

The primary purpose is that the jar file should be able to execute QA test cases in any remote or other system

Can someone please assist, its very important

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are trying to add a tar.gz robot-selenium dependency instead of a jar robot-selenium dependency.

Follow the instructions here:
https://github.com/Hi-Fi/robotframework-seleniumlibrary-java

And here: http://robotframework.org/MavenPlugin/index.html